# view_item Event variable data return "undefined"

Tags: google-tag-manager, custom-variables

I created trigger to fire when the view_item event occurs by using a custom event and setting the "Event" equals "view_item".  in preview mode when I check the view_item event, the built-in dataLayer.push is showing the item name.  I created a variable that will pull the dataLayer information from the "name" key.  When I inspect the "view_item" event, the variable I created shows up with the correct value of the item name.  However, in my tag, the `{{Item Name}}` variable is showing up as undefined.  I've tried to look for Google documentation on the ordering of the "view_item" event and the firing of the tags, but I couldn't find anything explicit.

Why is my "Custom HTML" tag that uses my `{{Item Name}}` variable showing as "undefined" when the "Variables" section shows the proper value?

Here is my custom html tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
voyage.event(6157, { productName: '{{Item Name}}', productViewed: '{{Page URL}}' })
</script>
```

The `{{Page URL}}` built in variable is showing properly.  I know it's loaded when the container loads.  But the `{{Item Name}}` variable is not showing.

If this is a hierarchy issue, how do I make sure that I fire this tag after the view_item event happens.

Also, what puzzles me is that I also have a GA4 event tag that is triggered by this same "view_item" event and the parameters I set for this event also have `{{Item Name}}` variable and the value is showing up correctly in this tag.

[image: Variables]

[image: Undefined]

Comment: add screenshots of your preview debugger for us to understand the issue better.

Comment: @BNazaruk added!